# Can Northbound interfaces (REST API) in a Software Defined Network (SDN) be used to manipulate QoS parameters?

Tags: network, layer3, packet-analysis, sdn, data

I am working on a project involving Quality of Service (QoS) manipulation in Software Defined Networks (SDNs). I know that the following parameters affect the QoS in an SDN:

- Time information (inter-arrival period)
- Packet information (e. packet length and direction of the packet)
- Protocol information e.g. IP/Port of source/destination and transport protocol
- stochastic information e.g. hurst parameter

I know that the first three parameters (timestamps, packet length, IP/Port of source/destination) can be manipulated through API requests. However, what about parameters such as hurst parameter that are not visible in the application layer?

Will packet manipulation in the data plane be more suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is it generally possible?  Definitely.

Ultimately this is going to be implementation specific, not all SDN implementations are the same.  For example, some implementation's REST APIs only allow configuration of a subset of features or only cover parts of a specific feature.

Depending on your requirements the specific method of implementation may be different as well.  For example, some SDN controllers are configured via Northbound API then take that information and configure the "network devices" via the controllers Southbound API.

Answer (score 0):

In short Yes, in the service abstraction layer which is your orchestration portion, you can define some policies that these policies than will translate to network policies like QoS.